# Is there a way to determine whether YouTube Shorts have paid content within using YouTube Data API v3 or otherwise?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Good day,

I'm trying to determine whether a YouTube Short contains paid content. I have read the API reference but failed to find any specific endpoint that can help with this. It is not part of the "Videos: list" response either.

Is there any way to see whether a YouTube Short contains any promoted content? Alternatively, is this information available anywhere? For example, I know that regular videos have a "This video contains paid promotion" plaques, but am uncertain about Shorts.

I'm using `google-api-python-client` to get the videos from the playlist (by using `playlistItems()` endpoint) and get information about them using `videos().list` endpoint, but the data I'm interested in is not included in the output.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible? Have you ever seen a short that contains promoted content? If you upload one, is there an option for it?

Comment: if the data is not included in the output, then you will need to look another way (if it even exists or is provided).